# How to replace current numeric values in a column to another value in R?

Tags: r

I have a column that contains multiple 13's, 14's, 15's..all the way to 24. I would like to replace each value, with the same interval of 1, but start with 1 and go to 12 (so 13 = 1, 14 = 2, and so on).

I tried using the apply function and ifelse statement to see if the condition is met, change to new value but I was not successful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `x - min(x) + 1`

Comment: wouldn't just subtracting 12 from the current values return what you need ? `x - 12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `match` to `match` to the value with the  `unique` values assuming the column is ordered

```
match(df1$col, unique(df1$col))
```

`match` returns the position index of the matching 'x' vector with the `table` values i.e the `unique` elements i.e.

```
match(c(12, 14, 12, 14), c(12, 14))
#[1] 1 2 1 2
```

Or with `factor` which can be coerced to `integer` to return the integer storage values of the factor, which would be starting from 1.

```
as.integer(factor(df1$col))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col = rep(13:24, each = 3))
```

Comment: wow - the match and unique worked. Would you mind explaining how that worked? I guess I should read up on the match, unique function in R..

Comment: Awesome. Now what if i wanted to change the numeric values to string values? so 13 = Oct, 14 = Nov, 15 = Dec, 16 = Jan? Similar approach? Trying to do less manual work on this and use functions/forloop.

Comment: @Dinho You can do this directly in `factor` i.e. `factor(df1$col, levels = 13:24, labels = c(month.abb[10:12], month.abb[1:9]))`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant - cheers man. Commenting now but makes sense what you did!

Comment: @Dinho  `v1 <- sample(13:24, 20, replace = TRUE); factor(v1, levels = 13:24, labels = c(month.abb[10:12], month.abb[1:9]))# [1] Nov Apr Aug Jun Feb Aug Jan Jan Jul May Mar Sep Oct Dec Nov Feb Jun Jan Jul Jan
Levels: Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep`

Comment: @Dinho It can become NAs if the values in the column is not 13:24 or if it is character i.e. it should match the `levels` we are entering in `factor`

Comment: I didn't realize the values werent 13:24 -__- worked like a charm. apprecaite the help man. and the explanation.